# Change certain columns into zeros

Tags: python, zero

I have an extremely large dataset XposMay (125,800 000). To make it easier, I made as smaller version below. I want to see which values in SomAprilMay are smaller than 3 and delete the corresponding columns in to zero. This is my code below, which does not change anything into zeros.

```
SomAprilMay=[0,0,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,15,12,14,1,10]
XposMay=[[50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63],
         [50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63],
         [50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]]
Xpos1May=XposMay
a=[]
b=[]
for k in range (0,len(SomAprilMay)):
    if SomAprilMay[k] < 3:
        a.append(SomAprilMay[k])
        b.append(k)
for m in range (0,len(XposMay)):
       Xpos1May[:][b[m]]=0
```

Since the first 7 and the last element of SomAprilMay < 3, the wanted result is:

```
Xpos1May = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,58,59,60,61,62,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,58,59,60,61,62,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,58,59,60,61,62,0]]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If you have such a large dataset, consider using numpy instead of storing the data in python lists. Processing python lists using handcrafted loops is **significantly** slower than numpy equivalents.

Comment: Yout most definitely will get a speedup from numpy. Something like `XposMay[somAprilMay < 3,:] = 0` should do the trick.

Comment: Shouldn't `SomAprilMay` contain the same number of items as each row in `XposMay`. In your example `SomAprilMay` has length 13 whilst each row in `XposMay` has length 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using numpy arrays for this task since this is faster than looping through the whole thing. However, the dimensions of SomAprilMay and XposMay lists are not equal, so I assumed you made a typo there and added another 14 before the final 1. This code

```
import numpy as np
SomAprilMay=np.array([0,0,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,15,12,14,14,1])
XposMay=np.array([[50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63],
         [50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63],
         [50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]])
XposMay.T[SomAprilMay < 3] = 0
XposMay
```

then yields the required

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,  0]])
```

Comment: what's T? I get the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'T'

Comment: .T is the short form of transposing, see the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T). This requires that you use a numpy array, not a list.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `XposMay[:, SomAprilMay<3] = 0`?

Comment: My personal preference is the transpose version, but I think they shouldn't differ in speed and thus one can use whatever one understands best ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `SomAprilMay` has 13 elements so I added one.

Here is a one liner:

```
SomAprilMay=[0,0,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,15,12,14,1]

XposMay=[[50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63],
         [50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63],
         [50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]]

mask = [e < 3 for e in SomAprilMay]

Xpos1May = [[0 if mask[i] else item for i, item in enumerate(sub) ] for sub in XposMay]
```

Comment: You could make this a bit more efficient if you precalculated which columns to change to 0. `mask = [int(i>=3) for i in SomAprilMay]; Xpos1May = [[mask[i]*v for i, v in enumerate(r)] for r in XposMay]` This uses multiplication by 0 or 1 to set the values to 0 or leave them unchanged. This is still very inefficient compared to `numpy`.

Comment: @mhawke Definitely should create mask for such large matrix :)